# You don’t have permission to save the file “project.xcworkspace” in the folder “jDiet.xcodeproj”.?

Tags: xcode, cordova, permissions, terminal

I'm still new with this PhoneGap and Xcode and I can't find the solution via Google.

After creating the file in the terminal, and try to open the Xcode project I get the following error:

> You don’t have permission to save the file “project.xcworkspace” in
>   the folder “jDiet.xcodeproj”.?

When I click OK, in the Xcode, I CAN'T modified the contents in the files, for example, the coding in index.html file.

Can you help me solve this?

I'm a new user here, so I cant post an image (snapshot) as I need a reputation of 10. Sorry.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just solved my problem by myself.

Right click on the file that terminal created, click get info and see the "sharing & permission".

I compare my **xcode folder** and "**this terminal created folder**" sharing & permission.

The name for "write and read" permission for this "terminal created folder" is under "**system**" name **instead** of my **username**, fakhrulzakry. So i click on **+** and **add** my username and set the Privilege to **Read&Write**.

:))

Actually I did this before i post this question, but i was wrongly choose the upper folder instead of the main folder for phonegap. So you need carefully check the exact folder .

Comment: Thank you F Z
After I saw your solution, I just typed just chmod 777

Comment: @F Z, i know this is old, but how did you find your "file that terminal created" ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked! After applying this solution, you may need to restart your Xcode in order this to work.

Comment: I had the same problem with the writing rights on the system user. This is because I ran the build command with a sudo prefix. Running it without the sudo will make your user the owner of the generated files.

Answer (score 1):

There was same issue for me but I am using ionic3 and here is info of the same-

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Node : v8.4.0
    npm  : 5.4.0 
    OS   : OS X Yosemite
```

And running code in xcode --

1. I open that dir `app/platform/ios`
2. Right click on ios.
3. changed permission as write & read.
   My issue resolved !